# Air for iOS Box2D multiple swf conflict

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, box2d

I have an app which contains several swf that are games. On the main screen of the app, you have icons, and each icon launches a game by loading the swf.

Everything works great on Android and Windows, but on iOS there is a conflict with the games using Box2D (in fact I'm using QuickBox2D, a shortcut of Box2D). When I launch a game containing Box2D i have this error :

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert Box2D.Collision::b2ContactID@103666911 to Box2D.Collision.b2ContactID.
at Box2D.Collision::b2ContactID()
at Box2D.Collision::b2ContactPoint()
at Box2D.Dynamics::b2ContactManager$cinit()
at Box2D.Dynamics::b2ContactManager$cinit()
at global$init()
at global$init()
at Box2D.Dynamics::b2World()
```

Strange thing is that I found that if I launch at first the game swf with the name in first position in alphabetical order, it works, and every other game works too. Example I have 3 swf of games with Box2D A.swf, B.swf and C.swf.
If I launch first A.swf it works, and B and C works too.
If I launch first C.swf, app freezes with the error.

I know compilation on iOS is different as the swf are all mixed up (something like that), but any help is appreciated thank you !

Comment: IIRC using more than a single SWF requires special precautions in order to reference and typecast objects from other SWFs. I don't remember details as I never used more than a single SWF, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

After hours I found a solution, using 1 instance of b2World for all the swf, rather than 1 instance by swf.
There is no conflict now, I guess all b2World instances where at the same level in iOS...
I leave it here for anyone having the same problem.